# Autolayout with imageview in portrait and landscape

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am beginner in autolayout.
I am currently facing an issue regarding laying out of an image.I have tried fixing this issue by adding constraints but i don't know how do i solve this.
There is an imageview that extends from one end to other end of the screen.It works fine for the portrait mode but when i switch to landscape the frame is fixed.I tried to do a aspect fill but that also doesnt seem to work.
How do i stretch the image upto the end for the landscape orientation.Or should i use some other image when orientation changes?
Images below demonstrate what i am getting and what i need? can anyone help?

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put this condition in viewddidload as well as viewwillappear

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)

{//LANDSCAPE
YOURIMAGEVIEW SETFRAME HERE

}else{
//PORTRAIT
YOURIMAGEVIEW SETFRAME HERE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In autolayout trying to set the frame of the imageView from the class file won't work as it will conflict with the constraint properties of the object.

Instead, you wish to set the constants so that the aligning edges of the object are always touching the side of the view.

Firstly I'd suggest selecting your imageView object and clearing the current constraints

[image: ToClearConstraints]

Then, whilst object selected, set the constraints manually by adding the constraints for the LHS and RHS distance to its holding view.

[image: Set the LHS and RHS constraints to holding view =0 on both side]

Using the interface builder / utilities panel to change and set the properties is the best way to set this automatic widening action.

The constraints can also be set programatically (which is useful if you want it custom animated etc) though, by having a play around with the constraints on the IB, you will eventually get the hang of it.

I hope this helps in some way.

Cheers, Jim.

Comment: thanks,i have found out that the above answer works great for  a normal view,but when i use it for container view it doesn't resize,any idea how to do it?